# Regex question with using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex with jQuery so it will search for two words in an attribute of an XML file.

Can someone tell me how to return a result that contains BOTH words (sport and favorite) in any order and any case (upper or lower case)?

```
var regex = new RegExp("sport favorite", 'i');

var $result = $(data).filter(function() {
                    if($(this).attr('Description')) {
                        return $(this).attr('Description').match(regex);
                    }
          });
```

Comment: Do they need to be right next to each other or just anywhere in the doc?

Comment: They can be anywhere in the attribute and separated by any words in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they may be separated by any character, you could do it like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(".*sport.+favorite.*|.*favorite.+sport.*", 'i');
```

(This assumes that no other word in the attribute *contains* the substring favorite or sport.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new RegExp("sport favorite|favorite sport", 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

The "\b" marker can be used to "match" the edges of words, so

```
var regex = /\bsport\b.*\bfavorite\b|\bfavorite\b.*\bsport\b/i;
```

matches the words only as words, and (for example) won't match "sporting his favorite hat".